# Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the map given by $f(z)=\sin z-z$. Then image of $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$. (T/F)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the map given by $f(z)=\sin z-z$. Then image of $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$. (T/F)

I think the statement is true, both $\sin z$ and $z$ is entire, so is $f$ and also by Picard theorem entire function can omit at most one point. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Note that $f(z+2\pi)=f(z)-2\pi$. If $f(z)\not =a$ for all $z$, this imply $f(z)\not=a+2\pi$ for all $z$.

Comment: @Kelenner , sorry but I cant understand properly

Comment: Your entire function can omit at most one point. But if $f$ omit $a$, then $f$ omit $a+2\pi $ also. So the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{C}$.